# simple sqlplus script doesn't seem to work

Tags: sql, plsql, sqlplus

When I type in:

```
C:\>sqlplus user/pass@OMP1 @CheckRowCount.sql
```

it connects but I don't see any results, in the .sql file I have this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as "rowcount" FROM dmsn.ds3r_1xrtt_voice_trigger;
```

I've also tried this

```
C:\>sqlplus user/pass@OMP1 SELECT COUNT(*) as "rowcount" FROM dmsn.ds3r_1xrtt_voice_trigger;
```

but all I get is the sql*plus commands to use in the CMD window

Comment: Were you able to connect to this Oracle database before?

Comment: figured it out...I actually forgot the ";" in the sql file :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't get anything in this way, if you want result from a script you must add a spool command to you script.

`spo result.txt;`

`SELECT COUNT(*) as "rowcount" FROM dmsn.ds3r_1xrtt_voice_trigger;`

`spo off;`

Then execute `C:\>sqlplus user/pass@OMP1 @CheckRowCount.sql` and open `result.txt` to see result.

Anyway for single script like this above just put it in sql> prompt and see what happens.

Comment: Or just type `cat result.txt` at the command line to display the file on your terminal.  Share and enjoy.